# NullPointerException when running on the phone (but not on emulator)

Tags: android

I want to display a list of the contact names from the SMS inbox and outbox (like in the native messaging app). I have come up with the following code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

super.onCreate(icicle);

Uri messagesUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(messagesUri,new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body", "type" }, null, null, null);
startManagingCursor(cursor);
String[] columns = new String[] { "address", "person", "date", "body", "type" };
String sms = "";
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
   while (cursor.moveToNext()){
       String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
       sms += address + " ";
       String contact=address;
       Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(address));  
       Cursor cs= getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},PhoneLookup.NUMBER+"='"+address+"'",null,null);
       startManagingCursor(cs);
       if(cs.getCount()>0)
       {
        cs.moveToFirst();
        contact=cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
       } 
       listItems.add(contact);
   }
}
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    listItems);
setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This works when I run the application in an emulator, but when I try to run it on a phone I get a NullPointerException. If I double-click on the error message in the LogCat the following line gets highlighted:

```
if(cs.getCount()>0)
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Check whether `cs` itself is valid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for ContentResolver.query(...)

> A Cursor object, which is positioned before the first entry, or **null**

You must always check for null when using a ContentResolver to query for data.

Also from the same documentation.

> Use question mark parameter markers such as 'phone=?' instead of explicit values in the selection parameter, so that queries that differ only by those values will be recognized as the same for caching purposes.

So instead of:

```
Cursor cs= getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[ {PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},PhoneLookup.NUMBER+"='"+address+"'",null,null);
```

Do:

```
Cursor cs= getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},PhoneLookup.NUMBER+"=?",new String[]{address},null);
```

Comment: Checking if the pointer was null solved the problem, thank you very much :) About the caching now, how can I pass the query parameter if I don't explicitly write it in the query? Sorry for the stupid question, but I am just starting with Android development :)

Comment: Strangely, now it works even if I don't check if the pointer is not null ^^

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that cs is null. As to why it is null, I suppose that the carrier/manufacturer could have changed how this is implemented on your device. Without knowing too much about how these systems work, it looks like you are querying against some kind of database and then using a cursor to iterate over the data. If the representation has been changed, the cursor will break. My suggestion would be to see if there is some other solution that is more Google/API driven (as opposed to reading the raw data).

Comment: Using the ContentResolver access the Provider, as the OP is doing, is the correct approach to accessing data that is published as part of another application. It is always represented as a Cursor, even if the implementation behind it decides to do something else.